# Swift::Compilation error - undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a compilation error that I just can't figure out.

The error I get is `Use of undeclared type 'MenuTabTableViewCell'`

My func is

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:MenuTabTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OptionMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTabTableViewCell

       //setting up the cell

    return cell
}
```

and my MenuTabTableViewCell class is very simple :

```
class MenuTabTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Menu: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var menu_Image: UIImageView!

}
```

I have tried to clean and re-build and I made sure the Target membershit is marked (two things I found that solved the same issue for some people here.)

Comment: Did you `import MenuTabTableViewCell` ?

Comment: When I try I get a different error  'No such module MenuTabTableViewCell'

Answer (score 0):

Check here whether it is available or not,[image]

If not available then add it to there

This tab will be available by selecting target and go to build phase and there you will able to see this compile resources add you cell class there if not available then clean and build

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue . It was quit stupid really, I had another viewcontroller with the same name in a different directory.